# Google sheets, flatten but with an added line

Tags: google-sheets, flatten

I have the following data in A1 to C5:

```
A   B   
C   D   E
F   G   
H       
I   J
```

I want to flatten this data so that each row is followed by a space, while removing the blank cells like this:

```
A
B

C
D
E

F
G

H

I
J
```

But when I use `FLATTEN`

I get this result:

```
A
B

C
D
E
F
G

H


I
J
```

it just treats the blanks in each row as data and slams it together.

I've tried to split and join unsuccessfully using a few variations on:

`=BYROW(A1:C5, LAMBDA(row,map(row,LAMBDA(x,if(x="",,x&",")))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
=FLATTEN(SPLIT (JOIN (",",BYROW(A1:C5,LAMBDA(row,TEXTJOIN(",",1,row)&","))),",",1,0))
```

Joining each row with commas, and an additional comma so it adds the extra cell when splitting